# My Plone default page is not pointing to my domain

Tags: plone

I just installed Plone and having trouble understanding how to have my Plone site default to my index page in Ubuntu.  I have tried using VMI and virtual_hosting monster but it is confusing.

Can anyone explain the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Use the [rewriterule witch](http://betabug.ch/zope/witch) to generate Apache rewrite rule configuration.

Set up your [Apache server](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.10/serverguide/httpd.html) to use such a rewrite rule to point to your back-end Plone server.

See the [Plone and Zope behind Apache](http://plone.org/documentation/kb/plone-apache) knowledge base article on Plone.org for the nitty-gritty details.